# Ionic 2, what is the "mode" input propertie in ion-input or ion-datetime

Tags: ionic2

In Ionic 2 doc [ion-datetime](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/datetime/DateTime/) and [ion-input](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/input/Input/) both have in their input properties the possible property **"mode"** as type String and with the following description:

> The mode to apply to this component.

I don't understand which data could possibly go there, and what would be the effect on the component.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you can see [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/platform-specific-styles/)

> Ionic uses **modes** to customize the look of components. Each platform
>   has a default mode, but this can be overridden. For example, an app
>   being viewed on an Android platform will use the **md** (Material Design)
>   mode. The  will have class="md" added to it by default and
>   all of the components will use Material Design styles.

And

> The following chart displays the default mode that is added to each
>   platform:

```
Platform    Mode    Details
ios         ios     Viewing on an iphone, ipad, or ipod will use the iOS styles.
android     md      Viewing on any android device will use the Material Design styles.
windows     wp      Viewing on any windows device inside cordova or electron uses the Windows styles.
core        md      Any platform that doesn’t fit any of the above platforms will use the Material Design styles.
```

> It is important to note that the platform and the mode are not the same thing. The platform can be set to use any mode in the config of
>   an app.

So regarding your question, maybe you want to display the `ion-input` component with the ios look and feel even if the app is being used in android, so you can use `mode="ios"` to do that.

Comment: Thanks, I had been reading thru that, but did not connect the information when I saw it in the properties of ion-input. Also ion-datetime is a bad example of "feel":) It does not work well, I struggled to substitute it with the native date-picker.

Comment: lol you're right. I've changed the example to use the `ion-input` component then :)